# Advantages of Windows 7 vs Windows Server 2008 for a home server

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, home-server

I'm about to setup a server/media computer in my home, but I don't know which OS to use. I'm currently running Ubuntu, but I dislike having to do use the terminal so much. I have configured a server running Windows XP before, so I know how to set up a server with a GUI.

The computer is going to be hooked up to two TV screens at the same time. I'm particularly going to use it for:

- Server apps (HTTP, ftp, svn, remote access, etc...)
- Spotify
- Watching HD movies
- Web surfing (with flash)

What would be the benefits of using Windows 7 versus Windows Server 2008? For home server use, is one more appropriate than the other?

Comment: Are you planning to host any sites (IIS)?

Comment: Yes, but with apache

Comment: Considering how much more expensive a Windows Server license is than a Windows 7 license, it seems unlikely that it would make more sense for you to use that.

Comment: I can get both legally for free though my school.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use TV cards with Windows Server 2008/R2, as it has no support for BDA drivers and it seems difficult or impossible to install Flash Player on Firefox <strike>or Chrome</strike>.

If you are using Apache for the web server, I cannot see what Windows Server can offer as any advantage as a media centre.

I have around 4 unused Windows Server 2008 R2 licences, but my HTPC runs Windows 7 Ultimate.

EDIT: You would have have more networking connections for BitTorrent though, and if your websites have a lot of concurrent vistors, but you can use a Windows Server 2008 virtual machine on the same physical machine for that.

Comment: @ Paradroid, There is a tcpip patcher for W7 to increase half open connections for bit torrent....http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/6045-windows-7-tcpip-sys-auto-patcher-remove-tcp-ip-connection-limit.html... one poster said the limit was raised to 120 in Windows 7 version 7068, so it may not be necessary to patch it.

Comment: Chrome comes with flash builtin.

Comment: Flash works fine on Windows Server in my experience. Chrome has Flash built-in and sandboxed now, so if you can install Chrome, you should be able to install Flash.

Comment: Oh yes, I just meant Flash on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 Home Premium (with its Media Center) will work for the things you have listed. [**Edited** after your response about using Apache]

Comment: I went with Windows 7 Pro and now the server is up and running with everything a was planning on using, thinks for the answers.